# How to get latitude and longitude Once you locate the marker in the map (Xcode+Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I started to use Google map in Xcode. Could you help me how can I get the values of latitude and longitude from inserted (clicked) marker?

If I log returned object I get scope which consist of latitude and longitude.. but I can not access to scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly find the answer of this with some google search or in the [google maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro) but I will try to help you out:

There is a delegate method `didTap marker` of google maps, you need to conform to `GMSMapViewDelegate` from your view controller to implement this method.

Inside that method, you can get **latitude** and **longitude** information of a marker from its position property. Refer to the code block below for better understanding:

Assuming your view controller is called `ViewController`:

```
extension ViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        //get latitude and longitude of a marker.
        print(marker.position.latitude)
        print(marker.position.longitude)
        return true
    }
}
```

Note: You don't have to write it in an extension though, you can just make your ViewController conform to the delegate in the actual class declaration.

Comment: extension AddPlaceController: GMSMapViewDelegate{ 
    func mapView(_mapView: GMSMapView, didBeginDragging marker: GMSMarker){
        print("Dragging Start")
    }
    func mapView(_mapView: GMSMapView, didDrag marker: GMSMarker){
        
        print("Did Drag")
    }
    

}